# Подсчитать значение цифр

Tags: php

Есть код

```
    foreach($o1->data as $v){
         if(preg_match('/dzintars/i', $v->url)){
            echo 'Просмотров: '  . $v->page_views++ . ', Ссылка: ' .
 $v->url . "\n";

         }
```

После него получаю такой результат:

> Просмотров: 16, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars
> Просмотров: 3, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars?tag=Be
> Trendy Просмотров: 2, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars?tag=Dzintars
> Actual Просмотров: 2, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars?tag=Декоративная
> косметика Кредо Просмотров: 1, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars?tag=NATURES
> RECIPE Просмотров: 1, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars?tag=ORGANIC
> STYLE Просмотров: 1, Ссылка:
> http://site.ru/catalog/dzintars?tag=ШАРМ

Нужно подсчитать количество просмотров.

Comment: @Exsol, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Типа вот так?

```
$total=0;
foreach($o1->data as $v){
    if(preg_match('/dzintars/i', $v->url)){
      echo 'Просмотров: '.$v->page_views.', Ссылка: '.$v->url."\n";

    }
    $total+=$v->page_views;
}
eсho "Всего просмотров:".$total
```